# controller path not detected by spring

Tags: spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, web

I have a little problem with the controller.What im trying to do is to return a html page using controller and my spring configurations and controller are given below

### my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">

<display-name>myapp</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myapp*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
  </web-app>
```

### my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean name="/" class="com.myapp.controller.MyAppcontroller" />
</beans>
```

### and my controller

```
@Controller
public class next{

@RequestMapping(value = "/next" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView homepage(){
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("next");
    return mv;
}

}
```

where "next" is the name of the jsp file which i would like to return but it gives me a error "404" for the link.Can anyone help me out  figure out where my problem lies.

Comment: are you able to hit homepage() method

Comment: What URL are you requesting?

Comment: I am trying to hit the url "localhost:8080/myapp/next" url

Comment: I am not able hit homepage() method.

Comment: You need to use full controller scan settings in context.xml

Answer (score 0):

this is problem with your url pattern in web.xml

change web.xml to :

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

With this url pattern work with every url.

Comment: Thanx promod . It works !! but all the .css and .js files are not detected

Comment: put css / js under WEB-INF/css

Comment: other wise put following entry in context.xml <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/"/>

Comment: I had fixed it .. we actually had to put all the *css , js using servlet mapping with servlet name default.Now my question is it detects only the myAppController class and the rest of the controller class were not detected.What can i do for this?

Comment: You can use spring component scan in context.xml